# When does numba just-in-time compile if recursion takes place?

Tags: python, recursion, compilation, numba

When I have a function that calls itself recursively without changing the type, but working on a large object (which gets passed around as an argument)... how does this work in numba behind the scenes?

Is my function (which is small but called a lot) just-in-time compiled the first time it is called, but not yet finished (because of the recursion) or does the compilation only finished if the first call to the function is finished?

For example in

```py
@njit
def myfct(large_object):
    a, tail_condition = do_things_1(intermediate_result)
    if tail_condition == True:
       return a
    intermediate_result = myfct(large_object)
    b = do_things_2(a, intermediate_result)
    return b

final_result = myfct(ref_to_large_object)
```

when is `myfct` compiled? Is it already compiled before it get called the second time in line 6 or is only compiled when I get `final_result` and everything is already done anyways? If the later is the case - how can I avoid that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions are compiled once per signature. If you don't provide an explicit signature, they are compiled the first time each signature is used:

```
@nb.njit
def f(n):
    return n * f(n-1) if n > 1 else 1

f(4)           # Compiled here
f(5)           # Already compiled
f(5.1)         # Compiled again
```

If you provide an explicit signature, functions are compiled when declared:

```
@nb.njit([nb.int32(nb.int32)])
def f(n):
    return n * f(n-1) if n > 1 else 1

f(5)           # Already compiled
f(5.1)         # Crashes. No attempt to compile an additional signature.
```

Providing more than one explicit signature:

```
@nb.njit([nb.int32(nb.int32), nb.float64(nb.float64)])
def f(n):
    return n * f(n-1) if n > 1 else 1

f(5)           # Already compiled
f(5.1)         # Already compiled
```

You can check this yourself by placing a breakpoint in `numba.core.dispatcher.Dispatcher.compile()`.

Comment: Great! Thanks! Also, for explaining how to make sure it is compiled during declaration. This is what I want - it even has an explicit type checking that way. Nice!